# Please explain the sequence of execution in the following code

Tags: c++, constructor, friend

1. I am trying to solve a quiz and came across this question.
   Please explain what happens internally that leads to this Output

   ```
   class B;

   class A { 
       friend class B;

       public: 
       ~A() {
           B boj();
           cout << "object A destructor " << endl;
       } 
   }; 

   class B  { 
       public: 
       ~B() { cout << "object B destructor " << endl; } 
   }; 

   int main() { 
       A a;
       A aobj(); 
       B bobj();
   }
   ```

   The output is:

   > Object A destructor
2. I am trying to create a program where a user enters if he wishes to add another record, and if yes then create a new object for that record.

   So if I am including constructors, then how do I create a new object every time the user wants?

   (If I give a predefined size to the array of object, then constructor will be called, say 50 times and initialize all 50 objects, while the user may only want to enter less).

Comment: One question per question, please. Which one would you like us to answer?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Yes, I already said that in my answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that was not directed towards you but towards OP. I was typing my comment while you were composing your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `a` is constructed. Then, `a` is destroyed.

The final two declarations in `main`, and the declaration inside `~B()`, are all local *function* declarations and therefore don't "do" anything.